Can I use the VS Code Edge devTools with a url and not only a file in my project?
I just found out you can open an edge browser window + the traditional chromium devtools window all within your vscode window panes. Which is amazing, this means I can full screen my vscode and do absolutely all my development through it!
The only thing is, that it seems you can only open file:/// protocol url's and not custom host setup local domains where you might be running a complex webserver setup for?
I don't need the file stepping and etc.. All I need is to be able to have the edge window and devtools window open within vscode using a custom URL like my.domain.top ?
Is this possible?
Did they remove the launch instance command? That seems to be I think what I'm looking for?

Yes, you can open a custom URL with VS Code Edge DevTools.
First, you need to install the DevTools extension for VS Code following this guide: Installing the DevTools extension for Visual Studio Code. Step 1-4 shows how to install the DevTools extension.
Then, you can click the Launch Instance button of the extension, it will open the Edge DevTools: Browser tab. Just copy and paste the URL in the address bar of the tab. For more information, you can refer to this doc: Get started by clicking the Launch Instance button.
However, the Launch Project button, along with a URL stored in launch.json, is the main way to open a webpage by specifying a URL, and the tools then open in Debug mode. For how to use Launch Project to debug, please refer to this doc: Get started by clicking the Launch Project button.

Wait WHAT. I am so confused, I think I had somehow stuffed up the "targets" view so it wasn't showing the Launch Instance button, but now after checking VSCode again that button is there clear as day and it launched a window I can navigate to a URL too with no worries! Thank you so much for the clear answer. My sincerest gratitudes

Yes, it is possible to open a browser window and the Chromium DevTools within VSCode using a custom URL. You can achieve this by using the Live Server extension or the Debugger for Chrome extension. Here are the steps to get you started:
Using Live Server Extension
Install Live Server Extension:
Open VSCode and go to the Extensions view
Search for "Live Server" and install it.
Start Live Server:
Open your project folder in VSCode.
Right-click on your index.html file (or any other HTML file) and select Open with Live Server.
This will open a new browser window pointing to a localhost URL.
